# Access matched_queries from a script_field

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way to access matched_queries part of a hit (resulting from named query) from a scripted_field?

For example, here I want to be able to access "Test1" and "Test2":

```
     {
        "_index": "mail_161212",
        "_type": "mail",
        "_id": "c166fa1e-0357-4398-9b1e-54eebb573c3a",
        "_score": 0,
        "fields": {
           "test_field": [
              "?"
           ]
        },
        "matched_queries": [
           "Test1",
           "Test2"
        ]
     }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [`SearchModule` implementation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/567c65b0d57e92cd530dafa7f55de7ba681af13e/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/SearchModule.java#L683-L691), you'll see that the fetch phase for script fields is executed **before** the fetch phase for matched queries, hence there's no way that script fields could access the matched queries (since the matched queries information does not exist yet).

Comment: I investigated the code further and it seems you're right, thanks